# Fixing the temperature of a large metal plate

Tags: temperature, heat, peltier

I need to hold a 60x60cm aluminum panel at a fixed temperature of 35 degrees Celsius. I thought about using Peltier elements but I'm not sure how easy it is to maintain a constant temperature with them. (Does anybody know of an off-the-shelf product that can do that?)

Another possibility is running heated water through brass pipes underneath the panel, but again I don't know of a good mechanism to keep the water at such a temperature.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: It also depends on the environment. If that can exceed 35C you'll need both heating and cooling.

Comment: @user_1818839 the environment is held fixed at 23 degrees Celcius

Comment: How thick? And is it OK to epoxy power resistors to  one side with active temp control?

Comment: How close do you need to hold the temperature to 35 deg C?  What is your cost target?  Are you trying to heat or cool something that is attached to the aluminum panel?

Comment: Consider aluminium tubing as aluminum will also corrode where its exposed surface contacts the brass plate because brass is more cathodic. The design of the plate and tubes will have a big impact on how close you can control the temperature as will your temperature controller. You need to define your problem in more detail. With the tubing will it be laminar or turbulent flow? Since you are heating you could use Power Resistors connected to the back of the plate.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Can be as thick as possible. Can you mention the component you had in mind?

Comment: @SteveSh Very close - preferably less than 1 degrees Celsius. And it's always about heating since we fixed the room temperature at 23 degrees. The cost is not an issue - it's for scientific use. Tnx

Comment: @Oren- Power resistors or heater strips are probably your best bet.  But, you need to do the proper analysis of your control loop (I assume there's going to be feedback of the base plate temperature involved).

Comment: @Oren - Also, are there any thermal or load transients involved?  Are you going to mount something to the aluminum plate and turn in on and off?

Comment: To accurately solve this one must know the mass and thermal resistance of objects on plate, air flow etc and effects of adding samples to warm plate to maintain 1 deg error max.  Ideally a solid slab of metal, sand, buckwheat or water as a constant temp with a regulated heat source at 35’C will be ideal with circulating air to prevent dT/dt from loads faster than heat source so that the plate has far greater heat mass than contents on plate

Answer (score 1):

Peltier is the best bet, you will need quite a few of them.

It is important to have good thermal non-rigid transfer, the best is to use thermal pads.

You will need a bigger base plate underneath the Peltier.

If you want something solid, regulate the Peltier with current (like a PWM would do) each independently and have a temperature sensor near each of them, have an MCU that manage the whole with a PID loop for each Peltier, this will give the best uniformity of temperature.

This method should yield a uniformity of temperature of less than 0.1°C.

The problem with the water, other than the mess to deal with leaks, is that your input temperature will be different than the output temperature, thus uniformity is difficult to achieve, also it will have a very slow regulation response as you have to heat the water, and to cool it it's even more trouble.